# Adding Site-wide Custom CSS

Tags: css

I'm quite new to Magento (ver 1.9.1.0).
I'm trying to add my own CSS that should apply to all pages.

I can't seem to make it work just by adding it on `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

Using the following:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom-style.css</name>
    </action>
</block>
```

My CSS is located at `/skin/frontend/base/default/css`.

I've seen some posts suggesting that I should add it into `layout.xml` but I can't see it anywhere on `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/`

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way to do this without using Layout XML Update from the Admin Panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open or create the layout file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
```

Then add your directive like this (example for empty file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/custom-style.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

As alternative variant, you can modify the `page.xml` file (if it exists in your theme):

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/custom-style.css</name>
            </action>
            ...
         </block>
     </block>
     ....
</default>
```

Comment: The alternative variant solved my problem. Except that I used this: `<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom-style.css</stylesheet></action>`

Thank you! Also for future readers, don't forget to clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just to create new file named new.css and add your theme folder given path below

```
skin\frontend\theme\default\css
```

link this css over here

app\design\frontend\theme\default\layout\page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/new.css</name></action>
</block>
```